# Alternatives to URLVoid and VirusTotal that can be run offline

Tags: detection, offline-caching, malware-detection

I am wondering if there are tools or products available that serve the same purpose as online tools such as URLVoid and Virustotal, but for offline use.
I have a machine that is not connected to the internet, so I can't query the APIs of online tools to check the Reputation of specific domains, I searched to see if offline versions (such as a database/cache/docker container exist) but could not find anything.

Does anyone know of such alternatives?

Comment: I have not come across any offline database that has IP reputation information. Since IP reputation is dynamic, you may not find any as due to the nature of the thing the information is updated on the above mentioned (and other) sites. Even by industry practice, reputation checks are done online.

Comment: @Ironluca thanks for your feedback, I do understand the problem where the dynamic nature of IPs and their reputability can change so more often than not we need to rely on online sources. But for example, I am using the GeoLite2 dbs from MaxMind and they offer the possibility to download the dbs for local use. I was wondering if the same option exists for reputations or other IP characteristics...